# Set Default Value For DropDownListFor Form Control From Database in ASP.NET MVC C# with "readOnly" attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

**Current Situation**
I am creating an intranet application using ASP.NET MVC for my organization to manage vehicle requests by employees. So far I am able to create, view, edit and delete request fine. However, one of my requests fields is the status values: pending; approved, etc) which I would like to g
et from the database into the DropDownListFor control, which I am getting, but now, instead, I would like to set the default value and dynamically (e.g, to "Pending") on the form and gray out the field.

I have the following **ASP.NET MVC** View code below:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Request_Status_Id, new SelectLis(Model.request_status_listings, "Request_Status_Id", "Status_Name"), new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Request_Status_Id", @readOnly = true })
```

**My Problem**
With the above code, I am struggling to set a default value without the user selecting it.

**My Attempt**
Setting this in the Controller action method, but this is were I am stuck.

Comment: Confused a bit here. Do you want to set the default value on the client side but just without user touching the drop down, or do you want to show it right away, pre-set on the server side?

Comment: There is no such hing as a readonly `<select>` - its not even a valid attribute. And what would be the point of rendering all that html for the options when you do not wnat the user to select one. Just use a readonly textbox (or a hidden input plus text) for the property.

Comment: Setting default value should performed from server-side, which later transferred to view. Also I disagreed usage of `DropDownListFor` as readonly input, just use `TextBoxFor` e.g. `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Request_Status_Id, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Request_Status_Id", @readonly = "readonly" })`.

Comment: @Andrei sorry for the confusion. Yes, I would like to pre-set on the server-side, the status of the field will be set to 'Pending' and user will not be able to change that value. The approver of the request will change the status upon acceptance.
I am going to implement and give you guys feedback. Thanks

Comment: @Stephen and Tetsuya, I absolutely agree  with your suggestions, and I think that is why I was also having trouble in wrapping my head around how to go about setting the dropdown. 

I am going to implement and give you guys feedback. Thanks